# Test Cases for Integration Testing for Instant Messaging Chat App

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I have created a Instant Messaging Chat App using Telegram Open Source Code for my College Project. Most of the functionality are similar to WhatsApp. I have created Test Cases for Unit Testing. But stuck in writing test cases for Integration Testing because exactly I don't know what to write in test case for integration testing.
Here I have attached test cases Format/Template for Unit testing.

[image: Test Cases for Unit Testing]

Please suggest test cases with Expected Input and Expected result for Integration testing-

Answer (score 0):

1.Test case for adding valid Contact
Input:Valid Phone number and name Expected output:Contact added successfully.Remarks:Pass

2.Test Case for adding invalid contact
Input:Add already added number to a group. Expected output:Duplicate number

3.Test case for creating Group Name
Input:Add a name with special characters like $, %, ' etc. Expected Output:Group name created successfully.

4.Test case for adding invalid Contact
Input:Add a number with alphanumeric values.Expected output:Invalid number.